# Wavefront set of a distribution and elliptic points on a manifold

Tags: elliptic-operators, pseudo-differential-operators, microlocal-analysis

Let $M$ be a smooth closed manifold, $E$ a Hermitian vector bundle over $M$ and $P$ a pseudodifferential operator. Let  $u\in D’(M,E)$ such that $Pu=0$. I want show that $$ WF(u) \subset T_0^{*}M \setminus \ell(P),$$ with $\ell(P)$ the set of elliptic points of $P$.

The thing is that I know that if $P$ is an elliptic pseudodifferential operator, and that $u \in \ker(P)$, then $u$ is smooth (so $u$ has no wavefront set). So my question is : can I use this result point by point, that is, if $(x,\xi) \in \ell(P)$, then as $Pu = 0$, $u$ is smooth at $x$, so $(x,\xi) \not\in WF(u)$ ? That would give the result.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Why can you assume $P$ is elliptic? If $P$ is elliptic, then the result is trivial.

Comment: @Deane I don’t, I just know this fact (if $P$ is elliptic then $u$ is smooth) and I am asking if I can use this result for each elliptic point of P (a general pseudifferential operator, with a elliptic set, not necessary equal to the whole cotangent space, ie not elliptic)

Comment: If you don’t assume $P$ is elliptic, how can you use a theorem that assumes the operator is elliptic?

Comment: @Deane I wanna use this result as follows : if $P$ is elliptic at $p$, then $u$ is smooth at $p$ (that is $\pi(p)$) (that is what I mean by « point by point »). I am asking if that is correct or not.

Comment: Ah, I see. But $\ell(P) \subset T^*_0M$, where I assume that $0 \in M$. If $P$ is elliptic at $0$, then indeed $\ell(P) = T_0^*M$ and the wavefront set is empty. But if you don't assume that $P$ is elliptic at $0 \in M$, then $\ell(P)$ is an open cone in $T_0^*M$. You now have to prove that the wavefront set, which is a closed cone in $T_0^*M$ is disjoint from $\ell(P)$.